# ngnix Url rewrite doesn't work

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

on my server i have installed **magento**,which is in my root directory. then I created a sub-folder named blog in my site's server. access the blog url is:

http://example.com/blog   http://example.com/blog/?p=123

when i checked  `Post name` item    `http://www.example.com/blog/index.php/sample-post/` in the Permalink Settings part. when i access post. it shows not found. when i unenabled the url rewrite. when view all the post is ok.